# Variations in the pronunciation of "the"

Tags: pronunciation, definite-articles, phonology, vowels

Although there are rather simple rules determining the pronunciation of "the", native speakers quite often deviate from these rules (including, e.g., TV shows). According to the Longman Pronunciation Dictionary,

> The EFL learner is advised to use [ðə] before a consonant sound (the
>   boy, the house), [ði] before a vowel sound (the egg, the hour). Native
>   speakers, however, sometimes ignore this distribution, in particular
>   by using [ðə] before a vowel (which is in turn usually reinforced by a
>   preceding ʔ), or by using [ði:] in any
>   environment, though especially before a hesitation pause. Furthermore,
>   some speakers use stressed [ðə] as a strong form, rather than the
>   usual [ði:].

My question is: when native speakers use [ðə] instead of [ði] before a vowel sound, do they do it on purpose or accidentally? If it is on purpose, how do they (typically) decide which pronunciation to use? What is a valid reason to use [ðə] before a vowel sound?

Comment: As a non-linguist and native American English speaker, I didn't learn about this "rule" until I was in my late thirties.  I should mention that I studied in University as an English Major for two years before switching my major.  Point being, for me the answer is always "accidentally" but my personal experience is insufficient for me to provide an answer in this case.

Comment: there are rules for pronouncing **the**? as a native speaker, i have never heard them. maybe it's because i just say what "sounds right", but this is definitely not something taught in schools. it really doesn't matter when you pronounce it each way. no one will notice or care.

Comment: Native speakers are not taught anything about the English language in Anglophone schools. Yes, there are rules for pronouncing _the_; they're the same rules as for pronouncing _a_ and _an_ -- one before consonants and one before vowels. Perfectly normal, like adding an extra syllable to plurals after a final /s/ or /z/. As to the OQ, /ði/ is the usual stressed variant and if the article is being emphasized, that's what'll normally come out. /ðə/ may be used as a default version by some people, but -- as witness previous comments -- no native speaker will ever notice the details.

Comment: There are a few English dialects where unstressed *the* is pronounced [ðə] before ***all*** words. Speakers of these dialects pronounce it this way automatically.

Comment: Collins mentions three different pronunciations, which fits my usage: the (stressed or emphatic ðiː; unstressed before a consonant ðə; unstressed before a vowel ðɪ). In the UK, it's very unusual to use [ðə] instead of [ði] before a vowel sound, and very unusual to use stressed [ðə] as a strong form, rather than the usual [ðiː].

Comment: Related: *[What is the pronunciation of “the”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1082)*

Comment: @choster thanks. I did look for a few minutes, but did not manage to find that question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To summarize the discussion here and elsewhere:

**In contrast to** the pronunciation-based distinction between **a and an**, the **pronunciation of "the"** is **not strictly determined** by the pronunciation of the following word. The guidelines in, for example, the Longman Pronunciation Dictionary are in fact just guidelines for non-native speakers. If one listens closely to native speakers, it becomes obvious that [ðə] and [ði] are chosen relatively freely, irrespective of the following word. Hence, it is interesting that people who learn English as a foreign language are usually told by teachers and textbooks that the pronunciation of "the" follows the same strict rule as the distinction between a and an. This misconception can even be found on English language sites such as [here](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/how-pronounce).

A similar answer was given [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/131354/the-vowel-sound).

Comment: It's not that remarkable ... there are some dialects of English that follow the rule that is taught in ESL. And you don't want to teach foreigners to always say /ði/, because that's going to sound bad. And you don't want to teach them to say /ðə əpɑrtmənt/, because that's hard to pronounce.

Comment: Thank you @PeterShor. I changed remarkable to interesting.

Comment: _The_ and _a(n)_ are entirely parallel: the variation in their pronunciation is dictated by the following sound, and some dialects/speakers do not display any variation at all. Just like there are people who say /ðə/ before a vowel, there are also speakers/dialects who say /ə/ before a vowel. And to **most** people, the variants are not chosen freely but based on the simple, pronunciation-based rule.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Prevocalic /ðə/ is far more common than prevocalic *a*.

Answer (score 1):

For rather a lot of English there are "rather simple rules" that are flat out wrong (the order of the letters "i" and "e" when together is my favorite example). You just have to memorize them.

In the case of "The", it is often pronounced with the long E sound for emphasis, which means that the same phrase might use a different pronunciation depending on the point the speaker wants to get across. The point of emphasis is often if the speaker wants to draw attention to the fact that it is somehow unique.

For example there's "The Ohio State University". If someone is just rattling off its official name, typically you'd hear the softer sound. However, many people are kind of annoyed at how insistent they are about the "The" at the front of the name (most US universities don't do that), so I often hear it pronounced with the harsher long E sound (and the entire word "The" louder than the rest of the name).

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware of the variations for the purpose of emphasis, but those do not explain the pronunciation used in, for example, American TV series and movies.

Answer (score 0):

The pronunciation ending with a long -e sound before a vowel also serves as what is termed "liaison" in speaking French. In English, using the long -e before a vowel, we can smoothly say "the eggs" (approximately, "thee-yeggs") instead of using a glottal stop: ("the [glottal stop] eggs").

Comment: I agree. However, if you, for example, compare different versions of Sinatra's "Love and Marriage", you will note that he sometimes pronounces "the" in "the other" as [ðə], even though [ði] seems to be easier to say and sing.

Comment: this is why i don't think it matters very much. native speakers differ their pronunciation of *the* based on more than just the succedent word (e.g. for emphasis or effect, or just as a personal habit), and we do this often. it really doesn't matter *that* much when you pronounce which way. *a* v. *an* matters WAY more in speech.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a rule anywhere. But based on some experiments in the last few minutes, I conclude that the short vowel before a vowel sound may just be a contraction or elision of the vowel sound. I might say "the eggs" with a long e, but what sounds like a short e is probably actually "th' eggs", pronounced with one syllable, not two.

[I'm in Texas, where slurrin's a fact o' life. That may make a diff'rence.]

Answer (score 0):

Those speakers who do not use the pronunciation "thee" for *the* generally do not have words that begin with a vowel. They use a glottal stop before what is an initial vowel for most speakers. These same people are often heard to use *a* where the "correct" article would be *an*. This is usually a regionalism that school teachers were unsuccessful in beating out of their students.

Comment: Useful additional info; do you have a source though? Looking at my own dialect, this phenomenon (starting vowel-initial words with a glottal stop, using "a" where "an" would be standard) seems to exist, but for me it's certainly not systematic. The wording of your answer suggests that it is for some English speakers; how do you know? Is this true for you, or have you read it somewhere?

Comment: It's not true for me or family members I grew up with, but growing up, I remember hearing this from people in both the South (parts of Kentucky and Tennessee) and in northern Ohio and southern Michigan (where I went to high school and college). I've always been fascinated by the way people talk, and I noticed the glottal stops early on.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve been fascinated by this phenomenon recently. I’m a non-linguist Canadian and I’ve always used the “an” and “thee” pronunciations before a vowel. I’m in my 70s. I recently started noticing on American TV that a large number of speakers consistently do not use these forms. It certainly doesn’t appear to be accidental. And then I even began noticing this phenomenon in some Canadian speakers. My observation is that it appears to be younger Canadians who are doing this. I’ve even been considering constructing a little reading “test” to see how some Canadians I know will pronounce these words in a text.

Today I decided to do a search to see if there was anything about this on the Internet and was really pleased to come across this discussion.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/424154)

Comment: "A ox"? The 'a hotel' vs 'an hotel' (both aspirated) issue has been discussed here before.