# Is "the" ever pronounced "knee"?

Tags: pronunciation, phonology, phonetics

Does the pronunciation of "the" sometimes sound like "knee"?

I have heard someone read it in a sentence sounded like 'knee'. The specific phrase was:

> pulling **the** extra layer of shirt off of her arms

Comment: Possible duplicate of "[Variations in the pronunciation of *the*](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/191979)"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is pronouncing "The" as in "Thee" still correct in titles?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5795/is-pronouncing-the-as-in-thee-still-correct-in-titles)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**TL;DR:**

Yes. Surprisingly, perhaps, the word *the* is sometimes pronounced [ni] "knee". This requires two processes. The first is phonological and relates to *the* changing to /ði/ when followed by a vowel. The second may be thought of  as phonetic, caused by coarticulatory processes. Often /ð/ is pronounced as an approximant. If the preceding consonant is a nasal, then the approximant may become nasalised thus effectively changing ð to a dental [n]. A native speaker will normally not notice this type of change, and will still recognise the word as *the*.

This kind of pronunciation is very likely in strings like:

- *in the end* [ɪn ni end]

But is also possible when the preceding nasal is [m] or [ŋ].

If you want to hear what this might sound like, there are some audio files at the bottom of this post.

---

**Full answer**

**The vowel:**

The normal canonical pronunciation of unstressed *the* is [ðə]. The first sound there is a voiced dental fricative. This sound has two main parts. It has voicing caused by the vibration of the vocal folds (also known as the vocal cords), and also audible friction caused by air becoming turbulent as it is forced between the tongue and the upper incisors (the upper front teeth).

The second sound [ə] is a mid central vowel.

However, word *the* is subject to certain phonological rules for most speakers of standard Englishes. When unstressed it is pronounced with a schwa, [ə], when it occurs before a consonant sound, but with a HAPPY vowel, [i], when it occurs before a vowel. (The HAPPY vowel is the vowel we use at the end of the word *happy*). So we see alternations like the following:

- the dog --> /ðə dɒg/ "thuh dog"
- the ant --> /ði ænt/ "thee ant"

So, with regard to the vowel in the word *the*, it is indeed often pronounced with the same vowel as the vowel in *knee*. How about the initial consonant though?

**The consonant**

Well, in the description above I noted that in a 'canonical' version of unstressed *the*, the initial consonant is pronounced as a dental fricative. This, however, is just how we think about this sound in an idealised kind of way. In real life the realisation of this phoneme is very often not actually a fricative at all. It is actually very often realised as an approximant. What this means is that the tongue still makes contact with the teeth but there is no friction involved. The air pressure in the mouth does not increase and there is no audible friction caused by air being forced out of a narrow stricture at high pressure. This is very important for the question here.

Now, when we speak, we have to make all sorts of adjustments so that we can pass smoothly from one sound to the next, or rather from one articulation to the next. In English we often have situations where a /ð/ is preceded by an alveolar consonant. An alveolar consonant is one that is made with the tip of the tongue on the alveolar ridge, that little shelf-like part of your mouth behind your top teeth. So in the phrases *all the time* and *in the end*, we see /ð/ preceded by the alveolar consonants /l/ and /n/ respectively. Now, if we were to pronounce this /l/ or this /n/ in its normal position, our tongues would have to suddenly jump from the alveolar ridge to the back of the top teeth to pass from one sound to the next. This acrobatic feat would also be undesirable causing there to be a lag between the /l/ or /n/ and the following /ð/. To get round this problem, we adjust the place that we make the consonant to match the place that we make the *th* sound. Instead  of our tongue touching the alveolar ridge, it touches the back of our top teeth. You will be able to detect the change if you say the following phrases:

- *all my*  - [l] on alveolar ridge
- *all the*  - [l] on back of top teeth
- *in law* - [n] on alveolar ridge
- *in the* - [n] on back of top teeth

In transcriptions we can show that these [l]s and [n]s are made on the teeth by using a little upside down tooth diacritic under the symbol: [ l̪, n̪].

This process is usually described as *anticipatory* because the /l/ or /n/ adjusts in anticipation of the forthcoming [ð]. However, when we see sequences like /lð/ or /nð/, we often see perseverative assimilation too. So we sometimes see features of the /l/ or /n/ spreading *forwards* into the following /ð/. In particular, if the underlying /ð/ is produced without audible friction, then the twangy nasal quality of the /n/ may carry through to the /ð/ if the velum remains lowered for the beginning of the word *the* (the *velum* is that flap of skin with a punch bag on the end that hangs down at the back of your mouth when you look in the mirror). If the preceding consonant is /l/, then the lateral [l]-like quality will spread to the following sound. The underlying [ð], will thereby effectively changed to a dental [n̪] or a dental [l̪] so that it matches the preceding sound exactly. So we often see pronunciations such as the following:

- [ɔ:l̪ l̪ə taɪm] "all le time"
- [ɪn̪ n̪i end] "in ne end"

**The Original Poster's example**

> pulling the extra layer of shirt off of her arms

For many speakers the *-ing* suffix in *pulling* will be pronounced with an /n/ instead of with the *ng* sound /ŋ/. In such cases we're very likely to see the following pronunciation matching the *in the end* example above:

- [pʊlɪn̪ n̪i ekstrə ... ] "pullin' ne extra ..."

However, what if the speaker uses an impeccable Received Pronunciation [ŋ] "ng" sound instead of an [n]?

Well, that flap of skin, the velum, that hangs down at the back of your throat does a very important job. It rises when we want to force air through our mouths, especially if we need to do so at high pressure. Alternatively, it can lower to direct air through our nasal cavities. If you start making a long [m] sound and then pinch your nose with your hand you will hear the [m] sound stop. This is because nasal sounds like [m, n, ŋ] direct the air out of your nose instead of your mouth. This gives them a metally kind of twangy sound. So for the [ŋ], the "ng" sound at the end of *pulling*, the velum will be lowered allowing air to leave through the nose.

Now, if the speaker is saying *the* with an approximant for the initial consonant, then they no longer need to suddenly force the air out through the mouth at high pressure. This means that the velum does not need to move so rapidly (the velum is a lumbering beast when left to its own devices). If the velum is down during the production of the initial consonant, air will continue to flow through the nasal cavity and the approximant will itself become nasalised. In other words it will be overlaid with that characteristic metally twang. So again, we have the tongue on the back of the upper teeth for the beginning of the first consonant in *the*, and again it is nasalised. In other words it will have transformed into a dental [n̪]. Most native speakers will not even  notice this and will automatically process the word as *the* without even thinking about it. But to an uninitiated but observant non-native speaker, this may appear quite odd:

- [pʊlɪŋ n̪i ekstrə ... ] "pulling ne extra ..."

In case you would like to hear what some of these examples might sound like, I have added some audio files below.

---

**Audio files:**

[Audio: *in the end* [ɪn̪ n̪i end]](https://vocaroo.com/i/s1B7mvGdRYcq)

[Audio: *all the time* [ɔ:l̪ l̪ə taɪm]](https://vocaroo.com/i/s1jeT1gWHdIP)

[Audio: *pulling the extra* [pʊlɪŋ n̪i ekstrə ... ]](https://vocaroo.com/i/s1XX4RKon4fU)

Comment: *Some* native speakers are aware of this occasional consonant shift; that's why "In-A-Gadda-Da-Vida" = "In the Garden of Eden".

Comment: Do you have some recordings of this phenomenon? Because I don't believe it.

Comment: @curiousdannii: which phenomenon do you mean: that the [ð] in "the" can assimilate to become a [n]-like sound, or that it can do so after any nasal consonant, even non-coronal [m] or [ŋ]? I have found reference to assimilation of /ð/ to a nasal after /n/ in various sources about phonetics; e.g. see the linked article which has a citation to "Manuel, S. Y.  1995 . “Speakers nasalize /ð/ after /n/, but listeners still hear /ð/,” J. Phonetics 23, 453–476." http://www.ling-phil.ox.ac.uk/files/place_assimilation_across_words.pdf

Comment: ...I hadn't come across the idea that this assimilation happens after nasal consonants other than /n/ before this answer, and I would like to see some references about that. Here is a blog post by Geoff Lindsey that mentions the /nð/ > [nn] assimilation with reference to audio from a George Lucas speech: http://englishspeechservices.com/blog/lucas-quiz-the-answers/

Comment: @curiousdannii Which particular phenomenon are you talking about.

Comment: The entire question, assimilation to ni.

Comment: @curiousdannii Well, I'm a bit surprised you need it, but have a look on any university website regarding connected speech processes in English. It's entirely well established. Not believing it is a bit like not believing that *the* changes to /ði/ before a vowel sound. Anyhow, [have a look at slide 2.3 here](http://www.depa.univ-paris8.fr/IMG/pdf/week11_consonants_in_detail-4.pdf). Otherwise ask any phonetician or phonologist at your uni who's conversant with English phonology or phonetics.

Comment: @Araucaria I accept nasalisation. I'm not sure about analysing the dominant sound as a dentalised [n] though rather than a nasalised [ð].  In any case, do you have a recording?

Comment: Or is there no real difference between ð̃ and n̪, it's just a notational convention?

Comment: @curiousdannii Well, [ð] necessarily involves turbulence and frication, which is absent in such cases. Whether [n̪] = /ð/ or /n/, I wouldn't want to say for sure. However, if you isloate the sound or a short segment in which it occurs, most native listeners would say it was an /n/. If you played the whole utterance, of course, they would swear it was /ð/. I'm digging around in my email to see if my buddy has sent me those sound files yet.

Comment: I guess it's a limitation of the IPA that there's no dentalised nasal symbol without using diacritics. I think the main reason why I'd want the dominant symbol to be ð is that the de-fricatisation you noted occurs commonly, not just in this nasalisation context, so this context is the more common de-fricatisation plus nasalisation. And the phoneme must surely remain /ð/ I would've thought, this is just a complex mix of phonetic processes.

Comment: Hmm. Wikipedia says that ð "is also sometimes used to represent the dental approximant ... but the approximant is more clearly written with the lowering diacritic: ⟨ð̞⟩" - so I'd say ð̃ or ð̞̃ is the best symbol. And I'd still want to say that the answer to the main question is no, because it doesn't get turned into a nasal *stop*. But maybe that's needlessly pedantic.

Comment: @curiousdannii Ok, couldn't find the files, so have coopted my colleague/guest to help me out! Files appended at end of post.

Comment: @sumelic It's not mentioned as such, but is implied in slide 2.3 [here](http://www.depa.univ-paris8.fr/IMG/pdf/week11_consonants_in_detail-4.pdf).

Comment: @curiousdannii The thing is, I would say the /ð/ **is** in fact quite commonly turned into an actual nasal (there is no such thing as a ‘nasal stop’ in IPA, just like there are no approximant stops—‘nasal’ and ‘stop’ are both manners of articulation and thus in complementary distribution), not just a nasalised dental fricative (definitely not an approximant, especially not after /n/). _In the_ can indeed become entirely homophonous with _innie_ (the navel type) for some speakers.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: the [official IPA chart as of 2015](https://www.internationalphoneticassociation.org/content/full-ipa-chart) uses the term "plosive", not "stop". I don't have access to the handbook, so I don't know if it defines "stop". [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occlusive) indicates that "plosive" is generally understood to exclude nasals, but "stop" is not necessarily.

Comment: @sumelic Which Wikipedia article claims that? The one on stop consonants has them as synonyms (which is how I’ve always seen them treated). A stop/plosive involves a complete occlusion of the airflow (the stop) followed by a release of the occlusion (the plosion); a nasal involves only occlusion of one half of the vocal tract, the lowered velum keeping the other half unoccluded. I do see that the Wikipedia page on nasal consonants says they’re also referred to as ‘nasal stops’; I’d call that a misnomer, and I’ve never heard it, but it does clarify Dannii’s comment.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: From the linked article on "occlusive": "The terms 'stop' and 'occlusive' are used inconsistently in the literature. They may be synonyms, or they may distinguish nasality as here. However, some authors use them in the opposite sense to here, with 'stop' being the generic term (oral stop, nasal stop), and 'occlusive' being restricted to oral consonants. Ladefoged and Maddieson (1996) prefer to distinguish 'stop' from 'nasal'."

Comment: All the audio links are broken. :/

Excellent answer, btw.

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul Hi there. Thanks. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find a (free) way of making sound files available permanently. That site had the longest free hosting for a sound file that I could find at the time. It's not possible, sadly, to keep uploading files on all my posts regularly in perpetuity. But in this case it's not possible anyway; I no longer have those files. [This post on ELL Meta  about sound files might interest you!](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5041/request-posting-a-supplementary-audio-clip/5047#5047).

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore.: I think link rot has eliminated your audio samples. You might see if you can find them elsewhere.

Comment: @Robusto Thanks :)  The site concerned only keeps files for a limited time. However, the files themselves, I believe, were on my partners ex-Mac. Now, probably part of  several recycled bottles and cans.

Answer (score 1):

[image: pronunciation of the word the]

I think **the** was the first word I ever learned to read, probably. *Webster's* (1959), gave the **pronunciation** as:

> **thu** [**short u** vowel sound, as in **up**] ;
>
> *before vowels*, **thi** [**short i** vowel sound, as in **it**] .

[image: thu]
[image: thi]

*Webster's* (1959 unabridged, New 20th Century, 2nd edition) did not include **thee** [long e vowel sound] , as an option -- although I personally pronounce it that way occasionally. Example:

- The[e] End

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  As a rule of thumb this often happens when 'the' is followed by words beginning with short vowel sounds (ă, ĕ, ĭ, ŏ, ŭ).

> The ant.
>
> The elephant.
>
> The insect.
>
> The octopus.
>
> The unidentified monster under the bed.

Comment: Or any long vowel sounds, or in fact, any vowel sounds at all.

Comment: How does this explain the change in the starting consonant of the word _the_?

Comment: @oerkelens - I don't think the OP is asking about that?