# Should one pronounce THE [in this case, THEE] when the following word begins with a vowel and THA when the following words begin with a consonant

Tags: pronunciation

THEE Apple, THEE Engine, THEE Imbecile, THEE Orange, THEE uncle and THA...for all [most] words beginning with consonants

Comment: There's no "rule" here.  It's mainly a matter of what fits the flow of words.

Comment: This is the traditional rule taught to ESL students. Many native speakers follow it most of the time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The + vowel letter](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/131354/the-vowel-letter)