# the and thee (I prefer to pronounce it as thuh all the time)

Tags: pronunciation, definite-articles, non-native-english, sandhi

My question is can I always pronounce THE with **thuh instead of thee**? Because unlike "a" "an" rule, pronouncing "thee" seems cumbersome for some people (including me)
Note that I know the "emphasis" and "vowel, consonant" rule about THE but I still prefer to pronounce it as thuh everytime. So can I??

Comment: Who will stop you if you do? If the answer is "no one", then of course you *can*. Whether you *should* is another matter entirely.

Comment: Do you mean you'd rather say _give me thuh apple_ instead of _give me thee apple_ ?

Comment: If you do, make sure you insert a glottal consonant between the vowel sounds.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is pronouncing "The" as in "Thee" still correct in titles?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5795/is-pronouncing-the-as-in-thee-still-correct-in-titles)

Comment: You could choose to pronounce "women" as woe men. "Sugar" as Sue grr. "Island" as is-land.

Comment: You can. Saying *thee* is not strictly necessary and makes people sound like they are trying hard to imitate the language as it was many hundreds of years ago.

Comment: @Tristanr - you say *thuh* eclipse? *thuh* evening? He's not talking about Thee and Thou here.

Comment: I remember reading somewhere that some dialects of English actually use *thuh* all the time. If you don't live in a region where these dialects are commonly heard, though, it might make you sound foreign and/or uneducated. But people will understand you.

Comment: medica, why not? Farooq might not have been specifically referring to thee and thou but, that's what saying *thee* brings to mind, considering that it is an obsolete, archaic word.

Comment: So, Thee apple, thee evening, the eclipse all sound hoity toity to you? Well, that's how things go with certain folk.

Comment: Your apple and evening examples, yes.

Comment: There's some discussion here with recordings: http://englishspeechservices.com/blog/it-wasnt-acceptable-in-d%C9%99-80s/

Comment: @snailboat - that was an illuminating and surprising link. I always wondered why some people said *tuh* for *to*. Fascinating. Obviously these uses more common than I realized.

Answer (score 2):

I hadn't thought about this at all but now I have I don't think I say *thee* for words that start with vowels.

*thuh apple, thuh energy plant, thuh interesting fact, thuh umbilical cord* it's all the same as *thuh dog*.
I might sound a bit more *theeish* when I say *the oil rig* but it's nowhere near a *thee* more like a very short *they* .

I do say *an apple* and *an hour* and my lack of *thee* didn't hold me back in life.

Comment: The most sense in the answers so far.

Comment: @Tristanr I'm common as muck, me.

Comment: You're not the only one!

Comment: That is the rule for both articles: *an* /ən/ and *the* /ði/ before vowels (vowel **sounds**, that is -- this is not a spelling rule); *a* /ə/ and *the* /ðə/ before consonant sounds. Since English speakers are not taught about the English language in school, it comes as a surprise to most of them that the most common word in the language has two different pronunciations that we vary automatically in context. Similarly, the fact that there are two different sounds spelled TH -- voiceless /θ/ as in *thin* and voiced /ð/ as in *this* is usually surprising.

Comment: @JohnLawler, I'm aware of the 'rule', what surprised me the most was that I don't actually do it. When I first read the question I assumed I did, hence my comment to the OP. When I thought about it more I realised that I don't _thee_ for vowels to any noticeable degree, except for unicorn. ;)

Comment: When two vowels come together in speech, there are several possibilities: one vowel can disappear, losing a syllable; something consonantal (like /n/ or the high front [y] offglide of /i/) can get inserted to separate them, preserving both syllables. If you say a phrase like _the uncle_ and _the apple_ as /ðə'əŋkəl/ and /ðə'æpəl/, then you hafta have some way to separate the two vowels, since one of them is stressed and the other's not. Glottal stop /ðə'ʔəŋkəl/? Vowel length /ðə:əŋkəl/? Combine them /'ðəŋkəl/? I don't know. Print is not the proper medium for discussing phonetics.

Comment: @JohnLawler There's definitely a (very very very short) gap between _the_ and _whatever_ not the run together _theeyapple_, _theeyuncle_ of some American accents. Not easy in print, I agree. I wonder if there are words that I'm forced to use _thee_ with? I'll need to pay more attention, or get a different accent!

Comment: Maybe (I almost wrote "Sounds like" :-) it could be a glottal stop. That's what separates the two OH's in _Oh-oh!_ /'ʔoʔo/

Comment: @JohnLawler _Oh-Oh_ has a kind of click that's missing in _the uncle_. I've had look around for IPA to speech and found this (one)[http://www2.research.att.com/~ttsweb/tts/demo.php] and used this (in Mikes voice) `<phoneme alphabet="ipa" ph="ðə:"> </phoneme> <phoneme alphabet="ipa" ph="əŋkəl"> </phoneme>` but there's way too much stress on the _the_. Do you know of any others? I'll play about with it until I can get him to say _the_ properly.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can: ***if and only if*** you find *a apple* and *a hour* to be grammatical.

I, personally, do not, and so cannot generate `/ðə/` before a vowel sound — in *my* language.

Remember that the English definite article has three distinct pronunciations. Per the OED, these are:

1. before a consonant sound: `/ðə/`
2. before a vowel sound other than /i/: `/ði/`
3. before another /i/ sound: `/ðiʔ/`
4. used emphatically: `/ðiː/`

You can of course do whatever you please; most people do.

But be warned that there are those who will think less of you, whether out of ignorance or intent, for flagrantly flouting established spoken English usage based not on made-up rules but on actual (phonologic) laws governing this.

Comment: "since English speakers are not taught about the English language in school"....  How, praytell, did you learn "about" it?  Apparently you are an auto-didact (or perhaps privately tutored). Clearly you know quite a lot about English. And you're right that most of us never have to think about the varied pronunciation of "the". We absorb that practice without "knowing the rule".