# What is the pronunciation of "the" before the vowel "e"?

Tags: pronunciation, articles, phonetics

How do you pronounce the vowel in the article "the" when used before "evil"? (American English)

Comment: Thank you! Can you tell me the inherent rule?

Comment: https://www.englishclub.com/pronunciation/the.htm

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/174034/the-and-thee-i-prefer-to-pronounce-it-as-thuh-all-the-time

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/131354/the-vowel-sound

Comment: 1: before a consonant sound: /ðə/.
2: before a vowel sound other than /i/: /ði/.
3: before another /i/ sound: /ðiʔ/.
4: used emphatically: /ðiː/.

Answer (score 4):

The general rule has [ði] before phonological vowel sounds, [ðə] before phonological consonant sounds. This is parallel to the use of ["an" and "a"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/152/when-should-i-use-a-vs-an).  However, there are a few complications:

- [ði] is also used in some cases as an emphasized form of the definite article; this can occur no matter what sound the following word starts with.
- You might on occasion hear an English speaker say something more like [ðə] or [ðɪ] before a word that starts with a vowel rather than the standard [ði]. Apparently, the use of a non-standard reduced form like [ðə] is most likely before words that start with a stressed /i/ or /ɪ/ sound, such as "evil". Even in this case, though, the standard pronunciation is still the most common one and the one that I would recommend for an English language learner.

If you want to learn more details, the following linguistics article is where I got this information: [Constraints on definite article alternation in speech production: To “thee” or not to “thee”?](http://link.springer.com/article/10.3758%2FBF03196110#page-1)
(by M. Gareth Gaskell , Helen Cox, Katherine Foley, Helen Grieve, Rachel O’Brien; *Memory & Cognition*
July 2003, Volume 31, Issue 5, pp 715-727)

Comment: An awesome reference. The research is based on British English, not American. The question is about American English.

Comment: @Darius: Good catch! I think the phenomena discovered might apply to American English as well, though... I did spend a few minutes "testing out" how I said the phrase "the evil" which seemed to me to confirm the conclusions of the paper.

Comment: Are you sure that [ði] is more common even before ['i]? I find [ði'i] very unnatural.

Comment: It seems that way in my personal usage. Gaskell et al. report that they found "more deviations from the normative rule
(i.e., reduced forms) for the high front vowels (15.1%)
than for the other vowels (9.9%)," but 15.1% is still clearly less common. They group together /i/ and /ɪ/; unfortunately I haven't been able to find separate data in their paper for just /i.

Comment: 'Phonetic vowels' like /w, j, l, r/ for example?

Comment: @Araucaria: Fixed wording. I've always heard /l/ and /r/ referred to as phonetic consonants.

Answer (score 1):

*the* is pronounced with as a long "thee" [ði] before the vowels.